# HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized SendGrid django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, sendgrid

I'm trying to do mail subscription on my django website I was following instructions online on how to achieve this. I went through it carefully but whenever I enter and email is say HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. I went ovewr the instructions and couldn't find were i went wrong.

Settings code
    FROM_EMAIL = 'newsletter@example.com' # replace with your address
    SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')

Models code:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    conf_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + " (" + ("not " if not self.confirmed else "") + "confirmed)"


class Newsletter(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    contents = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_newsletters/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject + " " + self.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    def send(self, request):
        contents = self.contents.read().decode('utf-8')
        subscribers = Subscriber.objects.filter(confirmed=True)
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        for sub in subscribers:
            message = Mail(
                    from_email=settings.FROM_EMAIL,
                    to_emails=sub.email,
                    subject=self.subject,
                    html_content=contents + (
                        '<br><a href="{}/delete/?email={}&conf_num={}">Unsubscribe</a>.').format(
                            request.build_absolute_uri('/delete/'),
                            sub.email,
                            sub.conf_num))
            sg.send(message)
```

Views.py

```
def random_digits():
    return "%0.12d" % random.randint(0, 999999999999)

@csrf_exempt
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sub = Subscriber(email=request.POST['email'], conf_num=random_digits())
        sub.save()
        message = Mail(
            from_email=settings.FROM_EMAIL,
            to_emails=sub.email,
            subject='Newsletter Confirmation',
            html_content='Thank you for signing up for my email newsletter! \
                Please complete the process by \
                <a href="{}/confirm/?email={}&conf_num={}"> clicking here to \
                confirm your registration</a>.'.format(request.build_absolute_uri('/confirm/'),
                                                    sub.email,
                                                    sub.conf_num))
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response = sg.send(message)
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'added', 'form': SubscriberForm()})
    else:
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'form': SubscriberForm()})


def confirm(request):
    sub = Subscriber.objects.get(email=request.GET['email'])
    if sub.conf_num == request.GET['conf_num']:
        sub.confirmed = True
        sub.save()
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'confirmed'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'denied'})

def delete(request):
    sub = Subscriber.objects.get(email=request.GET['email'])
    if sub.conf_num == request.GET['conf_num']:
        sub.delete()
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'unsubscribed'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'sub.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'denied'})
```

The error code that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emman\Documents\Online%20Shop%20Website\ShoeWeb\home\views.py", line 108, in subscribe
    sub.save()
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save        
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)       
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base   
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table 
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert  
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)    
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert   
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute  
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute   
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: home_subscriber.email
[09/Apr/2020 14:27:11] "POST /new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 154610
Internal Server Error: /new/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emman\Documents\Online%20Shop%20Website\ShoeWeb\home\views.py", line 120, in subscribe
    response = sg.send(message)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sendgrid\sendgrid.py", line 95, in send
    response = self.client.mail.send.post(request_body=message.get())
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 262, in http_request
    self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_http_client\client.py", line 178, in _make_request
    raise exc
python_http_client.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
[09/Apr/2020 14:27:29] "POST /new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 122106
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY') to SENDGRID_API_KEY = ('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
and verify users on sendgrid https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/